How to delete the last frame without reencoding the file using ffmpeg
I tried to use many variations of syntax but with no viable results.
The frames in the original file are 213214 and I want to omit the last frame for the total frames to become 213213 but when I try the below syntax I get a very weird result which a higher number of frames rather being decreased by 1
ffmpeg -copyts -i h:\dh.h265 -c copy -enc_time_base -1 -bsf:v:0 noise=drop='eq(pos\,213214)' h:\dh_framecorrect.mkv

so I tried this syntax
ffmpeg -i h:\dh.h265 -frames:v 213213 -c:v copy -c:a copy h:\dh_framecorrect.mkv

but again with no luck
then I tried another syntax like in below
ffmpeg -copyts -i h:\dh.h265 -vf "select='eq(n,213214)'" -vframes 213213 h:\dh_framecorrect.mkv

again with no luck
so what am doing wrong here, can anyone please help me out

If the stream has B-frames, you may not be able to do it (without re-encoding) since the last displayed frame. may be a P-frame stored out-of-order i.e. not in last place.

I'm not sure why the file has this extra frame!! the original file I used has 213213 frames but the file I ended up with after it got encoded in an AI tool has this extra frame, that's why I need to remove this extra frame so I can inject the DoVI RPU file without getting that there is a mismatch in the number of frames error.

@Gyan Could you please shed some light on how can I achieve that
